# Using Softlayer Object Filters for activeTransaction

Tags: python, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to use the Python SoftLayer API to return a list of virtual servers that are do **not** have an active transaction in "RECLAIM_WAIT" status (which is the state you have when you delete a virtual server in Softlayer). I am expecting to get back all virtual servers that have no activeTransaction at all, and also ones that have an activeTransaction but is in a status other than "RECLAIM_WAIT".

I call the vs manager with a filter that I think should work:

```
f={'virtualGuests': {'activeTransaction': {'transactionStatus': {'name': {'operation': '!= RECLAIM_WAIT'}}}}}
instance = vs.list_instances(hostname="node5-0",filter=f)
```

but it returns only instances that have an activeTransaction (including the ones that have a RECLAIM_WAIT status).

Here is an example of a returned instance from that call:

> [{'status': {'keyName': 'DISCONNECTED', 'name': 'Disconnected'}, 'datacenter': {'statusId': 2, 'id': 265592, 'name': 'xxxx', 'longName': 'xxx'}, 'domain': 'xxxx', 'powerState': {'keyName': 'HALTED', 'name': 'Halted'}, 'maxCpu': 2, 'maxMemory': 8192, 'hostname': 'node5-0', 'primaryIpAddress': 'xxxx', 'activeTransaction': {'modifyDate': '2017-01-16T05:20:01-06:00', 'statusChangeDate': '2017-01-16T05:20:01-06:00', 'elapsedSeconds': 22261, 'createDate': '2017-01-16T05:19:05-06:00', 'hardwareId': '', 'guestId': 27490599, 'id': 46204349, 'transactionStatus': {'friendlyName': 'This is a buffer time in which the customer may cancel the server', 'name': 'RECLAIM_WAIT'}}, 'globalIdentifier': 'xx', 'primaryBackendIpAddress': 'xxx', 'id': xxx, 'fullyQualifiedDomainName': 'xxx'}]

What am I doing wrong with the filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in your request, unfortunately, it's not possible to filter transactions for its **transactionStatus**, because the **transaction doesn't have access to "transactionStatusId" key**, you can check in the transaction datatype, there not exist the "transactionStatusId" in the local properties.

- [SoftLayer_Provisioning_Version1_Transaction](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Provisioning_Version1_Transaction)

So, the best way would be to filter directly in your code.